# liferay-maven-plugin deploy war from maven Liferay 6.2.5 (6.2 ga6)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, liferay

I had a portlet built for Liferay 6.1.1 ga2.
It's a maven project in eclipse.

I used to deploy that portlet with the `liferay-maven-plugin` using `mvn liferay:deploy`.

Now I'm trying to switch to Liferay 6.2 ga6 so I'm trying to redeploy that portlet with this new version but a strange error occurs using `mvn liferay:deploy` during the execution of the deploy:

```
[INFO] --- liferay-maven-plugin:6.2.5:deploy (default-cli) @ XXX-portlet ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: com.liferay.maven.plugins.PluginDeployerMojo
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.liferay.maven.plugins.PluginDeployerMojo not present
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:459)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/liferay/maven/plugins/PluginDeployerMojo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:242)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:107)
    ... 41 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.611s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Feb 17 10:36:44 CET 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
```

The plugin `liferay-maven-plugin` is defined as follows in my pom (with `liferay.version=6.2.5` and other properties that points to my local tomcat directory):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liferay.version}</version>
    <configuration>
            <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
            <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
            <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
            <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
            <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
            <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The version of java that I'm using is 1.6.0_21 and it's the same for the mvn command, in eclipse and on tomcat.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of [How to fix: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0-error) An advise for next time: Please search for the error message before asking a question here.

Comment: I knew it was a java version problem. But I had so many things in my build that it wasn't easy to find the one that actually triggered that and why.

Comment: You had problems to find `com/liferay/maven/plugins/PluginDeployerMojo`?

Comment: Clearly not. The real problem was to find out that this class has been compiled with a different version of java, and that was the reason of my prolem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was really a java version issue.
I changed the version of the JDK from 1.6.0_21 to 1.7.0_79 and now it's working.

Probably the classes of the plugin were compiled with a newer version of Java.